# Views: Sort items using contextual filter arguments

Tags: views

Im trying to create a block of "Related products", I have 3 criterias for show the related products: Color, Texture and size. These are taxonomy vocabularies.

In the view I can use contextual filters for get the matching products while viewing another product. These results are sorted alphabeticaly by default in the view.

Im trying to show first the items that match the Color of the product, then the ones that match the Texture and then those that match the size.

Can someone tell me if this is possible? and how would you do it?

This is the screenshoot of the view

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I would first get my contextual filters working so that my view was returning results for matching color, texture and size. Then I would use my Sort Criteria to add sorting filters to sort first by Color, then by texture, then by size. Order is important in the Sort Criteria.